# Passing Generic List<T> data from Controller to View using ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am Sending Data from Table after Grouping them and passing them to View by using view bag and want to display the data

I can Pass data from Controller to View but as the List includes List inside too it's a bit confusing for me

**Controller**

```
var data = (from e in `dc.tb`l
                        group e by e.a into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = g.Key,
                            `Task``Name` = g.Select(x => x.'task').To'List'(),
                            Task_Assignee = g.Select(x =>x.Name).To'List'(),
                            Task_Assigned_Date = g.Select(x =>x.U_Date).To'List'(),
                            Task_Completed_Date = g.Select(x => x.date).To'List'(),
                            Remarks_From_Assignee = g.Select(x => x.U_Remarks).To'List'(),
                            Remarks_From_Assigner = g.Select(x =>x.'rem').To'List'(),
                            Points_Given = g.Select(x=>x.Points).To'List'(),
                        }).To'List'();
```

how can I show the grouped data with respect to the user names in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a terrible idea. You cannot just pass around anonymous objects and keep it all type safe, and that's not the idea either. It's also a terrible query given those many inner queries.

Here's what you should be using, following common patterns and naming conventions:

```
public class TaskGroup
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Lists<TaskViewModel> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class TaskViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Assignee { get; set; }
    // rest of the properties
}
```

And you would use that by:

```
List<TaskGroup> data = context.TableName
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupingProperty)
    .Select(grp => new TaskGroup 
    {
        Key = grp.Key,
        Tasks = grp.Select(task => new TaskViewModel
        {
            Name = task.Task,
            Assignee = task.Name,
            // etc
        })
        .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: and how should i display the data in view page

Comment: @AmitKumarSharma `foreach` over the task groups and inside that `foreach` over the tasks? How else would you do it?

Comment: Thanks For Your Help. I did it just tweaked little things in the code